# Managing Configurations After Building Ember Application

Tags: ember.js

Looking for a *best practice* of **managing configuration** after the `ember build` if it is possible at all. Although it is not necessarily Docker specific, following must give you a good idea of the requirement even though you are not a Docker veteran.

**Motivation:** We use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) + Docker Hub to (automatically) build and deploy our backend and frontend applications separately. There are multiple deployments. Frontend application is based on [Ember](http://www.emberjs.com/) (using *ember-cli*). Instead of running `ember build --environment deployment-{1..N}` in a separate Dockerfile and end up having multiple Docker images, I would prefer having one single Docker image and running the Docker container with required settings passed as environment variables to inject them into the Ember configuration later, such as:

```
docker run -e ENV_APP_APIURL=deployment1.example.com ... --name deployment1 dockerimage
```

I would then run a small script as `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile which consumes these environment variables and inject them into the built Ember application so that web server can serve the re-configured application. In short:

```
[ember app] >> build >> [compiled generic web app] >> reconfigure(?) >> [final web app]
```

Is it ember way of doing things or I should go and grab a coffee?

Comment: It seems that there is a way to inject Docker environment variables into the build process. It is not exactly what I want. Yet, considerable: https://github.com/pk4media/ember-cli-docker-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about injecting meta tags into the index.html with your environment variables from your entrypoint script?  Then the Ember app could pickup these meta tags at runtime?

`ENTRYPOINT /start.sh`

my startup script does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -n $API_BASE_URI ]
then
   sed -i "/API_BASE_URI/c <meta name='API_BASE_URI' content='$API_BASE_URI'>" /app/dist/index.html; > /dev/null
 fi ]

exec "$@"
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>APP NAME</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="API_BASE_URI" content="/api">
...
```

Comment: Looks like the best and most generic option so far. Thanks.